# Magento order report showing wrong data

Tags: reports

I am facing issue for order data(prices) not showing correct in reports grid **Reports > Sales > Orders** for particular store. all other stores having correct data.

I have selected specific store, data range and click on **Show Report** button. Order reports grid is showing correct order count but all records having 0 prices.

It is showing correct prices in order grid **Sales > Order**.

I am having multi website + multi store website.
My all stores are showing correct data(all prices) but all prices for one store is showing price 0 always.

I have checked that order table **sales_flat_order** is having correct data, but order reports table **sales_order_aggregated_created** and **sales_order_aggregated_updated** are having price 0.

Table: sales_flat_order:
[image]

Table: sales_order_aggregated_created:
[image]

So, as per database, Order is having correct data but reports tables don't have correct data.

I have refreshed lifttime statics every time. it generates new entries but having wrong value for one store.

I have checked **Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Report_Order_Createdat::_aggregateByField** method and logged queries, after that I have run that queries to database. It is shoving 0 price for all.

That means There is something wrong when data fetch from order table and add it to reports table.

Can anyone guide me how can I debug it?

Answer (score 0):

There was issue with store currency setup. I have marked that **base_to_global_rate**  filed of table **sales_flat_order** is having 0 always.

This is because currency setup in admin **system->manage currency->rates** was not correct for that store.

**NOTE:**

There should be both currency selected in **Admin > System > Configuration > Currency Setup > Allowed Currency** for multi currency store.